# SwiftUI: @State variable never get updated from @Published

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, xcode13.2

I'm trying to trigger an alert when is an error in the model but it never get updated to show the alert:

Here is my implementation in the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var showAlert = false
    init() {
        viewModel = ViewModel()
        showAlert = viewModel.showAlert
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("This works"),
                  message: Text("Hello"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("got it"))
        )}
    }
}
```

Here is my models:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAlert = false
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        DoSomething.shared.showAlert.sink { _ in
            print("got new Value")
        } receiveValue: {[weak self] value in
            print("value")
            self?.showAlert = value
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
class DoSomething {
    let showAlert = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    static let shared = DoSomething()
    private init() {
        checkToShowAlert()
    }
    func checkToShowAlert() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { [weak self] in
            print("change value")
            self?.showAlert.send(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Any of you knows why the `showAlert` variable it never gets updated?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code, you're setting `ContentView`'s `showAlert` to the `ViewModel`'s `showAlert` at *that point in time*:

```
init() {
  viewModel = ViewModel()
  showAlert = viewModel.showAlert //<-- assignment at the time of init
}
```

Meaning, it's `false` at the time of assignment. Because it's just a `Bool` getting assigned to another `Bool`, there's no mechanism to keep it updated if `ViewModel`'s `showAlert` changes.

The simplest solution is to get rid of your `@State` variable and observe the `@Published` property directly:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("This works"),
                  message: Text("Hello"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("got it"))
        )}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we want it to be @ObservedObject in other words, will be re-instatiaited every time ContentView's body will be updated by SwiftUI ? 
Perhaps StateObject is better here wdyt ?

Answer (score 3):

Best remove the view model object, we don't need those in SwiftUI because the View struct holds the view data and the `@State` and `@Binding` property wrappers make the struct behave like an object.

Also, I don't think you need Combine for what you are trying to do because you aren't combining anything using `combineLatest` etc, but when we do use it in SwiftUI we don't use `sink` or `store`, instead we `assign` the end of the pipeline to an `@Published`.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Hello, world!")
                  .padding()
                Button("Show Alert") {
                    showAlert()
                 }
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Alert(title:Text("This works"),
                  message: Text("Hello"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("got it"))
        )}
    }
    
    func showAlert() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            isPresented = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: @user2924482 posted

Comment: But in my case the alert is been trigger by an issue in the model/backend. How can you apply this to show the alert in the model/backend ?

Comment: You just have a func like the showAlert func that makes the call to the back end and if an error is returned it updates the @ State to show an error.